# How does _XPG4_2 and other defines work on Solaris?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, solaris

On Solaris, in order to get the msg_control field in struct msghdr and have IPV6_TCLASS I seem to need to define _XPG4_2 and __EXTENSIONS__.

It seems to work if I just define these to 1 before including anything:

```
#if defined (__SVR4) && defined (__sun)
# define _XPG4_2 1
# define __EXTENSIONS__ 1
#endif
```

1. Should I do it this way?
2. Do I need to define them in all source files, or bad things may happen?
3. Is there a list of these things somewhere?

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029849/what-is-the-bsd-or-portable-way-to-get-tos-byte-like-iprecvtos-from-linux).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`man -k XPG4` reveals that there is a `standards(5)` man page, which lists the feature test macros and library linking info for various standards, including the following:

> X/Open CAE
>        To build or compile an application that conforms to  one  of
>        the X/Open CAE specifications, use the following guidelines.
>        Applications need not set the POSIX feature test  macros  if
>        they require both CAE and POSIX functionality.
>
> ```
>  SUS (XPG4v2)
>        The application must define _XOPEN_SOURCE with a value
>        other    than    500    (preferably    1)    and   set
>        _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED=1.
> ```

Grepping through `/usr/include` for `_XOPEN_SOURCE` turns more information in `/usr/include/sys/feature_tests.h`:

> application writers wishing to use any functions specified as X/Open UNIX Extension must define `_XOPEN_SOURCE` and `_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED=1`.  The Sun internal macro `_XPG4_2` should not be used in its place as unexpected results may occur.

So defining `_XPG4_2` yourself is not the way to do it.

If any structure definitions depend on these macros, you would definitely be better off defining them in all translation units. The easiest way to do that is to specify them on the compiler command line:

```
cc -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=1 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED=1
```

If you're using `make`, you should be able to do this by adding the `-D` parameters to the `CFLAGS` variable:

```
CFLAGS += -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=1 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED=1
```